# Inherited class doesn't get stored in Windows Azure Mobile Service

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am in a process of creating a library for Windows Azure. So, here is a simple generic method to insert a new record:

```
public <TEntity extends SyncableBase> void addRemoteItem(TEntity itemToAdd) {
    MobileServiceTable<TEntity> remoteTable = (MobileServiceTable<TEntity>)mobileServiceClient.getTable(itemToAdd.getClass());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(itemToAdd);
    remoteTable.insert(itemToAdd, new TableOperationCallback<TEntity>() {
        public void onCompleted(TEntity entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                Log.e("SuccessMe", "Success");
                // Insert succeeded 
                } 
            else { 
                Log.e("SuccessMe", "Nah "+ exception.getMessage());
                // Insert failed 
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Now, here is my SyncableBase class:

```
public class SyncableBase {
    @SerializedName("Bingo")
    private int localId;

    //@SerializedName("id")
    private String remoteId;

    private boolean isDeleted;
}
```

And my ToDoItem class:

```
public class ToDoItem extends SyncableBase {
    private String name;
}
```

Now, the problem is: This fails with `Error processing request`. But if I don't extend `ToDoItem` from `SyncableBase` and move all those members directly to the former, everything works just fine. As can be seen, I tried serializing my Java object just before calling inset. The serialized json is exactly the same in both the cases. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of debugging, I have come up with a potential problem and it's definite solution. This holds valid for the Android Azure SDK valid at the time of writing this. A couple of notes:

1. For seamless transactions, the `id` member must be present in the inherited class and not the super class. While validating the object, Azure SDK uses reflection and tries to find a filed with name (or serialized name) equal to `id` or `Id`. Somehow, the member isn't found if it is present in super class and we get error.
2. GSON (the thing which serializes Java object to JSON) is configured inside SDK so that it serializes even the null members. So, when there are no columns in WAMS table (fresh table) and try to insert an item with null fields, the error is thrown. The filed must hold a value so that the type of corresponding column to be generated can be determined. A new field with null value will give you an error.

Here's an example of an item being put in a fresh table.

```
{
    "id": "Awesome unique id",
    "name": Beautiful Wallpaper",
    "description": null
}
```

Here, the WAMS would know that it has to generate a column called `description`; however, it wouldn't know the type of this column. Hence, first object must always have non-null values.

In my particular case, both the problems are there. Taking care of these things solved them.